# Dealing with argc and argv

Tags: php

I wrote the code as follows:

```
<?php
array_shift($argv);
$taskid=$argv[0];
$file1=file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$file2=fopen($argv[2],"w");
echo $taskid."\n".$file1."\n".$file2."\n";
?>
```

I execute this program as `php myfile.php 1 1.txt 2.txt`
Where 1 is the taskid, 1.txt is the input file and 2.txt is the output file.
I want to modify this program in such a way that it runs even though I don't pass any arguments that is like `php myfile.php` should run. I want to place an if condition for that. I worked with the conditions like `if(*argv<=1)` and if(argc==NULL) etc., but none of them are working.

I need a perfect condition that checks if no arguments are passed then my program should show a user friendly message.

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($argc !== 4) {
  // show message
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd add that since the question is specifically about no arguments so I'd vote for `if ($argc === 1)` in that case

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
array_shift($argv);

if (empty($argv) || count($argv) != 3) {
  echo "Incorrect number of arguments\n";
}
else {
  $taskid = $argv[0];
  $file1 = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
  $file2 = fopen($argv[2],"w");
  echo $taskid . "\n" . $file1 . "\n" . $file2 . "\n";
}
```